# Mono.whenDelayError with 3 parameters are only taking the last 2 parameter

Tags: java, project-reactor

The issue can be reproduced with the following test

```
Mono<Tuple3<Integer, String, Long>> mono = Mono.whenDelayError(Mono.just(1), Mono.just("one), Mono.just(1L));
StepVerifier.create(mono)
.expectNextCount(1)
.verifyComplete();
```

The issue lies in Mono.java lines 864, where it only takes p2 and p3.

I'm using version 3.0.4.RELEASE

I have raised [issue](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/issues/333) and [pull request](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/pull/334)

Comment: thanks for raising it and the PR, it'll be fixed in Reactor 3.0.5

Comment: @SimonBaslé any ETA on version 3.0.5?

Comment: tentatively jan. 27 2017

Comment: Note I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is clearly a bug report. There is no actual question, and the issue was debugged and a ticket opened on github.

Comment: the close vote should not prevent you from continuing asking questions on SO (eg. when you wonder if you used an operator correctly), but if you clearly found a bug, as here, do not hesitate to directly report it as a github issue.

Comment: @Wins, if you could move the resolution to an answer and accept it, that will keep the question within the guidelines, as it stands though, there is no question here and it will probably be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue with version 3.0.4 which will be fixed in version 3.0.5 as Simon stated.